# What is the good ORM for .NET that does concurrency well?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, concurrency, devforce

I am looking for a well rounded ORM that handle concurrency with ease for .NET. It should also be threadsafe.

Any recommendation? Pls elaborate why you choose this particular ORM.

Comment: What function would an ORM preform that's not thread-safe?  It builds queries (which should be purely functional), executes them, and translates the resultset into an object graph.  If someone has managed to implement this in a non-thread-safe manner, something has gone horribly wrong.

Comment: "What function would an ORM preform that's not thread-safe?" -- Do two identical queries return two objects graphs (graph instances), or do they return the same object graph/instance?

Comment: @jrockway: I think you're vastly underestimating the problem of O/R mapping. Real-world ORMs do much more than that. NHibernate, for example, implements several cache levels. See http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/24/NHibernate-and-the-second-level-cache-tips.aspx . Keeping it thread-safe with so many caches is *hard*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best thing to use today is still NHibernate.  It has been around the longest (see Hibernate for java) and just gets it done.  Also, there are many tools out now that make working with it much easier.  It blows LINQ to SQL out of the water in terms of features (though not ease of use).  The Entity Framework in version 1 is not ready for use.  The next version (Entity Framework 4.0) will be much better and may be worth looking at once it is out.

Comment: I choose this one before I end up choosing NHibernate. It seem that the NHibernate community is extremely active as of late. Plus, like other have mentions, it's feature rich.

LLBGen come a close second for me as the lead developer, Frans Bouma is also very active in the communities. I looked at home LLBLGen handle concurrency and I am still struggle with the concept...

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand the threadsafe part of it.Assuming that you are referring to db access I'd say Nhibernate does this best IMHO(though handling concurrency is fundamental to any ORM).

Ideally I would want to live in a world where each one gets his turn for the pie. Unfortunately that won’t happen and until then I would try one of [these strategies](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/15/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency.aspx) with Nhibernate.

> Optimistic, Dirty,
>   Versioned or Pessimistic

Apply these based on your need.
Your choice of an ORM should be based on how active the community and eco-system behind it is and not just by its feature set(though that's a factor of the community).

Additionally, take a look at [NHProf](http://nhprof.com/) , [Linq to NH](http://codebetter.com/blogs/kyle.baley/archive/2008/04/07/trying-out-linq-for-nhibernate.aspx) , [Nhibernate Search](http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/?p=21) and [Nhibernate Validator](http://nhforge.org/media/p/7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford it IdeaBlade's DevForce is a sophisticated framework that goes beyond an ORM tool. It would be my recommendation for LOB enterprise applications.

Is a comprehensive platform that enables enterprise .NET development and deployment for n-tier environments. Provides sophisticated object persistence, client-side caching, advanced data binding, business rule validation, support for offline/disconnected operations, and support for publishing and consuming Web Services, among its many features. It also includes the Business Object Server (BOS), an application server that provides scalability, security, and enables n-tier deployment of .NET applications across the internet.

Comment: I didn't have time to evaluate this product.

Answer (score 1):

LLBLGen Pro is one of the good ones. I am using it in my project and it is doing well. I can not compare other O/R mappers available with LLBLGen pro because I am using O/R Mapper first time. It is not free but I think it is good one to spend money on.

These links might help.

http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2004/03/06/85125.aspx
http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx

But do tell us which O/R Mapper you choose for your project. This will help us to make decision in future.